# Tkinter : get font used by windows 10

Tags: windows, tkinter, fonts, get

Is it possible to get the font which is used by Windows in the interface ? I mean, to know which one is selected in the computer’s settings (Arial, Times, ...)
Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Try `families()` provided by `tkinter.font` module.

Comment: I searched, but it doesn't help me to get the current font used by the system :/

Comment: What do you mean "current font used by the system"?

Comment: I mean the font which is used by Windows 10 in all the interface (on the desk, in the settings, in the dialogboxes, ...)